# MySQL log filling up with unwanted "Status information" on server reboot due to SIGHUP

Tags: mysql, logging

This has been plaguing me for a while, so it's time to ask.

The MySQL `error_log` fills up with "Status information" when the server reboots due to `SIGHUP`. Here is a link describing the behavior: [MySQL Server response to SIGHUP signals](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/unix-signal-response.html)

I understand what's going on, but don't know how to fix it.

I have one script that controls the starting/stopping of mysqld: [/etc/init.d/mysql](https://pastebin.com/raw/84fjNfh7)

And [here is the sourced mysql-helpers file](https://pastebin.com/raw/BEkhtPxh) referenced by the init.d script.

I can't find where the SIGHUP is coming from? Or maybe it's coming from the OS? Debian 10.

**Edit**

Doing `service mysql restart` or `stop` never produces the extra log entry, so maybe it has something to do with the shutdown process during server reboot|halt? I don't understand SIGHUP enough to determine if I'm on the right track or not.

Comment: Please add details about your operating system. Is your init.d-script being called during an orderly shutdown of the system?

Comment: OS is Debian 10 Buster with default kernel. The init.d script is called during `shutdown -r now` or `shutdown -h now`. I'm not sure if it's an "orderly" shutdown or not.

Comment: Is this a VM or a physical machine? I only ask because (many) years ago I had encountered an issue where a lot of SIGHUP was due to failing memory, so doing a memory test may be useful.... but this if definately clutching at straws. I'd first start with seeing what else is running on the box. Any monitoring / metrics / configuration management?

Comment: SIGHUP is sent to MySQL when you do a things like flush grant tables or logs... is the behaviour you are seeing due to tools such as logrotate? Is there anything odd going on the the mysql.users table etc.? What can you determine based on when the activity happens?

Comment: @CameronKerr The machine is a VM. No monitoring software running. The only thing I can think of is possibly the replacement of `killall` with `mysqladmin shutdown` in the /etc/init.d/mysql script. Not sure though. Knowing *when* SIGHUP is sent to mysqld is helpful, though. In the meantime, any other suggestions are more than welcome.

Comment: if during shutdown your init.d-script is not run, all remaining processes (including mysql) will get a SIGHUP followed bei SIGKILL it smells like this is what is happening there.

Comment: @Nils Your comment turned out to be the correct answer. If you'd like to post an answer, I'll mark it as correct. The final solution turned out to be changing the start/stop script from sysvinit to systemd.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If during shutdown your init.d-script is not run, all remaining processes (including mysql) will get a SIGHUP followed bei SIGKILL it smells like this is what is happening there.

Comment: That's exactly what was happening. Switched from init.d to systemd and everything is peachy now.